# Beamer navigation bullets without text

Tags: beamer, navigation

How can I show navigation bullets without text above? In the following example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\begin{document}
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Sec 1}
\begin{frame}
1
\end{frame}
\section{no text}
\subsection{no text}
\begin{frame}
2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want no text above the second dot.

Comment: but you want the dot, right? I have a solution, but do you need the tableofcontents in the document?

Comment: @Moriambar The same as me?

Comment: @TeXnician I used `[\space]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use an "empty" section (fully empty does not work, but you can fake it).

[image: dot]

```
\section[~]{no text}
\subsection[~]{no text}
```

Please note that this will also remove the text from the toc. If you use table of contents this will cause trouble.

Comment: thanks. I need the toc, but I use \tableofcontents[sections={1}] to omit the last section